# django admin static files are uploaded to s3 via `collectstatic` but not served when running locally

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm following [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/) for storing static and media files on s3. This is what my static files configuration in `settings.py` looks like:

```py
USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'
## AWS Configuration
if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None # differs from the tutorial because the bucket is private
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles'
```

After setting all the env variables I run `python manage.py collectstatic` and I can see that the files have been successfully uploaded to my s3 bucket. I.e. I see `static/admin/` directory on s3 with fonts, css, etc.

However when I run the server locally the admin panel is missing all the css. I'm not sure why django cannot find the admin static files given that `collectstatic` worked. I found several other tutorials [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/), [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) and [here](https://swapps.com/blog/store-django-static-assets-with-amazon-s3/) but I can't find what I'm missing. For all of them it seems like it's supposed to "just work" after running `collectstatic`... What did I forget?

**Note** The admin panel is fine when `USE_S3 == False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the objects in the s3 bucket weren't public. I made the assets public and now it's working.

Comment: lol you owe me a minute from my life span :)

Comment: BROOOOO after reading a 100 SO questions, your answer just saved me! you the man